# Nodejs different content-length

Tags: javascript, node.js, content-length

I'm downloading an image from internet (from Box), and I'm getting different `body.length` and header `content-length`.

The response header `content-length` is equals to `75739`.
But `body.length` is equals to `72818`.

Now look at this, if I run `request(url).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('image.jpg'))`, the image got 75739 and open correctly.

Altough, if I run `fs.writeFileSync('image.jpg', body)`, the image got 137515 and doesn't open correctly.

I also did this gist so you can test by yourself: https://gist.github.com/Daymannovaes/54663e0718f0ded40285d0666f937179

I don't know if encoding is the problem, but I tried to get the byteLength with all the encodes and none of them was to correct size:

`length of the body (ascii) 72818
length of the body (utf8) 137515
length of the body (utf16le) 5636
length of the body (ucs2) 145636
length of the body (base64) 54613
length of the body (latin1) 72818
length of the body (binary) 72818
length of the body (hex) 36409`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer. Thanks to a friend of mine. I don't know if is fault of the request library, but if I set `{ encoding: 'binary' }` at the request, everything works fine.

Comment: yep, that's the answer